# Lower estimation for trace of a product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let $X\succ0$ and $Q$ are square real matrices.

For $Q\succ0$ we have the estimation
$$
  {\rm Tr}(XQ)\succeq{\rm Tr}(X)\lambda_{\min}(Q).
$$
Is it possible to obtain the similar lower estimation for (nonzero) positive-semidefinite matrix $Q\succeq 0$?

Comment: Your first inequality is incorrect as stated. For example, it does not hold for 
$$
X = -I, \quad Q = \pmatrix{1\\&2}.
$$

Comment: You are right, I forgot to note that $X\succ0$.

Comment: We can also say that $\operatorname{Tr}(XQ) \geq \operatorname{Tr}(Q) \lambda_{\min}(X)$. If both $X,Q$ are non-invertible, then the best that we can say is that $\operatorname{Tr}(XQ) \geq 0$.

Comment: You might find it interesting, however, that we have
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(XQ) = 0 \iff XQ = 0
$$
when both $X,Q$ are positive semidefinite

Comment: Thank you very  much! May I ask, is the inequality $${\rm Tr}(XQ)\succeq{\rm Tr}(X)\lambda_{\min}(Q)$$ valid for $X\succ0$ only? Or for $X\succeq$ as well?

Comment: @m The inequality holds for $ X \succeq 0$ as well